# How do I create multiple menus for different pages in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, hyperlink, menu

How do I add a link from the home page that goes to a new page with a different menu?

Example: from home page, click on 'Sales Department' menu link, which goes to the Sales Department page. This shows a new menu with ten new menu items on the Sales Department Page.

I am able to create menus, menu items, blocks and pages but unsure how to build a multi-menu structure as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Menus, by default, have a UI presence in the form of a block.  Within each block, you can specify which pages it will or will not show.  This will give you the appearance of having content/page specific menus.

For instance, menu1 will only show on /home.  Within menu1 there is a link to a page called /contact.  On /contact, there is another menu (menu2) with links /contact/email and /contact/phone.  For the menu1 block, the specified pages are `/` and `/home`.  For the menu2 block, the specified pages are `/contact` and `/contact/*`.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing around, this is what worked for me:

1. Create a new page called "Human Resources Page".
   Link to parent item "Navigation Page".
   Enter a menu link title "Human Resources Page" (otherwise it will not appear in menu).
2. Create a new menu called "Human Resources Menu" (human-resources-menu)
   Show block on specific pages: `<front>`.
3. Add menu item called "Organization Chart".
   Attach to parent menu "Human Resources Menu".
4. In blocks, assign "Human Resources Menu" to "Right Sidebar"
   Set "Page specific visibility settings" to `hr*`.

Answer (score 0):

Add menus in blocks and specify in which page each menu should be visible. Look in the `block` setting properties: you can add the pages there.